# Problem when drawing an axis-aligned bounding box around a tilted rectangle.

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, bounding-box

I need to draw an axis-aligned bounding box containing a tilted rectangle for a report about physic engines.

My initial idea was to simply insert a rectangular node, apply a rotational transformation to it and then draw the bounding-box with the fit library of `tikz`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

I tinkered with the original idea and wrote the following code. The idea is that I insert four hidden nodes, corresponding to the corners of the rotated rectangle, and then I fit a box around them.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Draw the rectangle
  \coordinate (R) at (7,3);
  \node[rectangle,rotate=-30,minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm,inner sep=0pt,draw=black] (rect) at (R) {};

  % An invisible node at each corner of the rectangle
  \begin{scope}[rotate around={-30:(R)}]
    \path (R) node () {}
          ++(-1,-1.5) node (a) {}
          ++(2,0) node (b) {}
          ++(0,3) node (c) {}
          ++(-2,0) node (d) {};
    \end{scope}

  % Draw the bounding box
  \node[fit=(a) (b) (c) (d),draw=green,dashed] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is an image of the current result:

[image]

Is there an easier way to do that?

Bonus question: How could I get rid of the spaces between the rectangle and its bounding box (it want them to be touching)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the corner nodes of the `rect` node, instead of defining them yourself.

If you just say `fit=(rect)`, the fit command would assume that you mean `(rect.north)`, `(rect.east)`, etc., which doesn't help in this case because you need `(rect.north east)`, `(rect.south east)`, etc., but it's good to know anyway.

To get the outer rectangle to touch the inner one, set `inner sep=0pt` for the outer rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Draw the rectangle
  \coordinate (R) at (7,3);
  \node[rotate=-30,minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm,draw=black] (rect) at (R) {};


  % Draw the bounding box
  \node[fit=(rect.north west) (rect.north east) (rect.south east) (rect.south west), draw=green,dashed,inner sep=0pt] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fit]